# Need help formatting a get request to access a particular property in my databas

Tags: angular, http, get

I'm working through Todd Motto's Ultimate Angular Pro Course and I'm noticing it's a bit outdated. I'm stuck on the video that is dealing with resolvers. Specifically, I'm struggling putting together a get request to access a particular property in my database. The video that I'm on is teaching about resolvers and putting together one to access messages in a folder for an email program.

Here is my service where I'm trying to put my get request.

```
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable} from "@angular/core"; 
import { Observable } from "rxjs";
import {Mail} from "./components/models/mail.interface"; 
import { catchError, map } from "rxjs/operators";




@Injectable()
export class MailService {
    folderUrl = 'http://localhost:3000';
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    

    getFolder(folder:string): Observable <Mail[]> {
        const folderData = this.http.get<Mail[]>(`(folderUrl+/messages)?folder=${folder}`);

        return folderData

        
    
    }
    }
```

and here is the database that I'm trying to get data from.

```
{
  "messages": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "folder": "inbox",
      "from": "Jane Smith",
      "summary": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lobortis, neque at ultricies fringilla, ligula metus",
      "timestamp": 1487848162905
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "folder": "inbox",
      "from": "John Doe",
      "summary": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lobortis, neque at ultricies fringilla, ligula metus",
      "timestamp": 1487845787719
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "folder": "inbox",
      "from": "Joseph Hanes",
      "summary": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lobortis, neque at ultricies fringilla, ligula metus",
      "timestamp": 1487845787719
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "folder": "trash",
      "from": "Laurence Murray",
      "summary": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur lobortis, neque at ultricies fringilla, ligula metus",
      "timestamp": 1487845787719
    }
  ]
}
```

I've reviewed the angular docs and youtube. Now I'm turning to you guys. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you having issues with the get request?
If that's the problem you can write your request to list your emails this way.

You can access the folderUrl variable trough "this", since it belongs to the class you are in, and to send the filters you use one object.

```
getFolder(folder:string): Observable <Mail[]> {
    return this.http.get<Mail[]>(`${this.folderUrl}/messages`, {folder: folder});
}
```